# How to get the ID from one dataframe to match the name from another datframe in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have two dataframes one has the **ID** and **Name** and one just has the **Name**. I want to match the name to the ID and for those without a ID leave as null.

DF1:

```
ID       Name 
 1      John Doe 
 2      Mary Sue
 3      Josh Smith 
 4      Sarah Moore
```

DF2:

```
Name  
Sarah Moore
John Doe
Josh Smith 
Mary Sue 
Josh Gordon
```

Desired output:

```
ID       Name
 4      Sarah Moore
 1      John Doe
 3      Josh Smith
 2      Mary Sue
 NA     Josh Gordon
```

I've tried merging but have not gotten the results I needed

```
df2 = df2.merge(df2,df1['ID'], on = 'Name', how = 'left')
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `df1.merge(df2, on='Name', how='right')`

Comment: Could having null values cause an issue for this. Nothing I seem to do works.